# What is the Icosahedral Matrices?

Tags: virology

This [website](http://viperdb.scripps.edu/mat.php?tnum=60) introduces the "Icosahedral Matrices".

1. What are the locations of the other half?

It only shows around 30 numbers of the 60 facets. So how to know the other 30 numbers on the back?

[image]

2. The 60 transformation matrices are shown below in the website. Are they rotational matrices? What are the exact meaning of those 9 numbers for a particular matrix? For example,

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I’m voting to close this question because it is much more likely to get answered on other SE sites, like Mathematics.SE. If you want to transfer this question to another site, please request migration instead of reposting. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If possible, can we wait for a few days? It is an interdisciplinary question. And I think the virologists are more likely to answer it.

Comment: Sure! Closing a question requires 5 votes; that would give plenty of time for others to see and possibly answer it.